# If $ \ x_1=2 , \ x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{2}+\frac{1}{x_n} \ $ ; show that $ \ x_n^2-2>0 \ $ for every index $ \ n \ $

Tags: induction

If $ \ x_1=2 , \ x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{2}+\frac{1}{x_n} \ $ ; show that $ \ x_n^2-2>0 \ $ for every index $ \ n \ $.

**Answer:**

For $ \ n=1 \ $,

$ x_1^2-2=2^2-2=2>0 \ $

For $ \ n=2 \ $,

$ x_2^2-2=(\frac{x_1}{2}+\frac{1}{2})^2-2=(1.5)^2-2>0 \ $

Let for $ \ n=m \ $,

$ x_m^2-2>0 \ $

Now we have to show that $ \ x_{m+1}^2-2>0 \ $

B**ut how to show** that $ \ x_{m+1}^2-2>0 \ $ ?

Help me

Comment: Letting $x(n) = \sqrt 2 \; y(n)$ the recursion becomes $y(n+1) = \frac{1}{2} (y(n) + 1/y(n))$ but this is $\gt 1$ for $y(n) \gt 1$. As $y(1) = \sqrt 2 \gt 1$ the inequality holds for all $n \gt 1$ which in terms of $x(n)$ proves the assertion of the OP.

Comment: Just for completeness: the recursion has the symbolic solution $x(n)=\sqrt{2} \coth \left(2^{n-1} \coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\right)$ from which we also can conclude that $x(n)^2 \gt 2$ noticing that $\coth(z) \gt 1$ for $z>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: prove $x_{n+1}^2-2=(\frac{x_n}{2}-\frac{1}{x_n})^2$.

Comment: we have to show that $ x_{n+1}^2-2>0 \ $ but you showed $ \ x_{n+1}^2-2=(\frac{x_n}{2}-\frac{1}{x_n})^2 \geq 0 \ $.

Comment: @yourmath I didn't prove anything; I gave a hint. One need only verify $\frac{x_n}{2}\ne\frac{1}{x_n}$, i.e. $x_n^2\ne 2$. Clearly, all $x_n\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Can you teach me how to comment   to a particular  user just you did in the comment "@yourmath". ?  How can we do this here?

Comment: @yourmath Just type @ followed by their name. (Depending on your device, a suggested name can be clicked on to save time.) Unfortunately, I've found this doesn't work on my phone; it gets deleted.